# Programatically added Auto layout does not updates when orientation is changed

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have a a scrollview in which i create and add tableviews programmatically in a loop and while adding each table in scroll view i also call my function 'addConstraintsOnTblView' to add contraints.
This works fine with both orientations only if you open it in that orientation and does not change it. Once it is loaded and you change the orientation then scrollview whose constraints are applied in storyboard update properly as expected but table views orientation does not update accordingly.
Please let me know what's wrong.
I tried applying tblsScrollView.updateConstraints() in viewWillTransitionToSize but it's not updating.

Here is my code

```
func createTblViews {

    for i in 0..<array.count {
           let tblView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 382, height: Int(self.tblsScrollView.frame.height)))
        tblView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DiskDataTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "drivedatacell")
        tblView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        tblView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        tblView.separatorStyle = .None

        tblsScrollView.addSubview(tblView)

        self.addConstraintsOnTblView(tblView, xConstraintVal: CGFloat(i * 382)) // 382 is width of each table
        self.tblsScrollView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()


     }
}

func addConstraintsOnTblView(tblView: UIView, xConstraintVal: CGFloat) {
    let leadConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tblView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: tblsScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: xConstraintVal)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tblView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: tblsScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top , multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tblView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 382) // 382 is width of each table

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tblView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: tblsScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    tblsScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    tblsScrollView.addConstraints([leadConstraint, topConstraint, widthConstraint, bottomConstraint])

}
```